# Extracting clusters in the form of lines from a dataset

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset similar to the one shown below, that clearly forms lines from my point of view. Instead of drawing markers, I want to connect the markers within each curve by a line. I am curious, in this case, what type of clustering algorithms would be a good one?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed = 42

#Generate (x,y) data
x = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,50)
y = x%1
x += np.sin(2*x%1)
y = y%0.2

#Shuffle (x,y) data
ns = list(range(len(x)))
np.random.shuffle(ns)
x = x[ns]
y = y[ns]

#Plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].scatter(x,y)
axs[1].plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("markers vs lines.pdf")
```

**Figure** - Left: Markers, Right: Data points connected by lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for Clustering Algorithm, you may want to look at DBSCAN.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html

There is two parameters, epsilon and the number of point to make a cluster.

Here is a code to get you started:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed = 42
%matplotlib inline

#Generate (x,y) data
x = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,50)
y = x%1
x += np.sin(2*x%1)
y = y%0.2

#Shuffle (x,y) data
ns = list(range(len(x)))
np.random.shuffle(ns)
x = x[ns]
y = y[ns]

"""
    Fit the Data 
"""
X = [i for i in zip(x,y)]
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

"""
    Compute the DBSCAN
"""
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=1).fit(X)
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_clusters_

"""
    Plot the clusters
"""
d= dict(zip(set(labels),['red','green','blue','yellow','purple','grey']))
d[-1] = "black"
plt.scatter(x,y,color=[ d[i] for i in labels])
plt.show()
```

The result :

[image: Graph color result from DBSCAN]

Inpired by : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html

More about the parameters of the DBSCAN here : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN

Hope this help.

Comment: Excellent, DBSCAN does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Such data is common in image analysis, due to architecture.

In order to infer perspective, people have used the Hough transform to identify lines of points'.

That is probably the best method to use here.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand it correct, Hough transform works well if the shape of the curves is known (e.g. a straight line or a parabola). In principle that is the right answer for the plots shown above. However, in my case I do not exactly know the shape of the curves. Tbaki's answer suits this case better, since DBSCAN does not need to know about the shape of the curves.

Comment: They only need to be close enough to a line; they can't be a circle. DBSCAN is an option (you should then maybe use 4C clustering, which is based on DBSCAN?) but you will see it fails if the lines get too close to each other.

Comment: Thanks, the 4C algorithm seems to be a good extension to my problem. However, the simple DBscan version is sufficient in my case.